# Seekbar progress drawable not displaying and API 23

Tags: android, xml, view, seekbar

I have a custom SeekBar that uses LayerList as progress drawable. On Android device with API <22 it seems to work fine, however on API 22 the progress drawable is not displayed.

Here's my LayerList code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
        <gradient android:startColor="#0e0e0f" android:endColor="#373938" android:angle="270"/>
        <stroke android:width="10dp"
            android:color="#2d3035" />
        <size android:height="3dp" android:width="500dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#45ab12" />
            <stroke android:width="10dp"
                android:color="#2d3035"  />
            <size android:height="3dp" android:width="500dp"/>
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

And here's my Seekbar:

```
 <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:splitTrack="false"

                android:thumbOffset="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/firstAudioPositionSeekBar"
                android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_bg"/>
```

Here are screen shots of the SeekBar on API 22 and lower:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code on your Activity/Fragment where you handle this SeekBar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having similiar issue on API 22 and found your question. Did you find a good solution for that? 
 What I've noticed till now, with many experiments: 
1. Without solid on API 22 the progressbar is drawn 
2. Stroke values are drawn different on API 22 devices than on all upper APIs, what is very strange, cause it doesn't even take care of screen size.. what the hell? 
3. Even when u change stroke to proper one on API 22 - it still is MUCH MUCH different on small resolutions (480/800) and all other screen sizes..

I found a solution thought, but I don't think it is the best one. I created 3 separate drawable files (layer list): one for API 22 with small resolution, one for API 22 with all other resolutions, and one for all API's above 22. I removed stroke from those with API 22 and put inside item values:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:top="15dp" android:bottom="15dp">
```

I have tested it for 10 different phones with different resolutions - it works perfectly, even for big tablets. Still, I think there must be a better solution for this.

Best regards,
Max